# Can't load data from hive: -chgrp: 'LONEWOLF\Sudarshan' does not match expected pattern for group

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm very new in `Hadoop`. I have created employee table in `Hive` and loaded data in it using text file now I am trying to load data saved in table but getting following. I searched everywhere but found nothing. Can someone help me with this?

```
hive> select * from employee;
-chgrp: 'LONEWOLF\Sudarshan' does not match expected pattern for group
Usage: hadoop fs [generic options]
        [-appendToFile <localsrc> ... <dst>]
        [-cat [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]
        [-checksum <src> ...]
        [-chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...]
        [-chmod [-R] <MODE[,MODE]... | OCTALMODE> PATH...]
        [-chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] PATH...]
        [-copyFromLocal [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] <localsrc> ... <dst>]
        [-copyToLocal [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]
        [-count [-q] [-h] [-v] [-t [<storage type>]] [-u] [-x] <path> ...]
        [-cp [-f] [-p | -p[topax]] [-d] <src> ... <dst>]
        [-createSnapshot <snapshotDir> [<snapshotName>]]
        [-deleteSnapshot <snapshotDir> <snapshotName>]
        [-df [-h] [<path> ...]]
        [-du [-s] [-h] [-x] <path> ...]
        [-expunge]
        [-find <path> ... <expression> ...]
        [-get [-f] [-p] [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> ... <localdst>]
        [-getfacl [-R] <path>]
        [-getfattr [-R] {-n name | -d} [-e en] <path>]
        [-getmerge [-nl] [-skip-empty-file] <src> <localdst>]
        [-help [cmd ...]]
        [-ls [-C] [-d] [-h] [-q] [-R] [-t] [-S] [-r] [-u] [<path> ...]]
        [-mkdir [-p] <path> ...]
        [-moveFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
        [-moveToLocal <src> <localdst>]
        [-mv <src> ... <dst>]
        [-put [-f] [-p] [-l] [-d] <localsrc> ... <dst>]
        [-renameSnapshot <snapshotDir> <oldName> <newName>]
        [-rm [-f] [-r|-R] [-skipTrash] [-safely] <src> ...]
        [-rmdir [--ignore-fail-on-non-empty] <dir> ...]
        [-setfacl [-R] [{-b|-k} {-m|-x <acl_spec>} <path>]|[--set <acl_spec> <path>]]
        [-setfattr {-n name [-v value] | -x name} <path>]
        [-setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path> ...]
        [-stat [format] <path> ...]
        [-tail [-f] <file>]
        [-test -[defsz] <path>]
        [-text [-ignoreCrc] <src> ...]
        [-touchz <path> ...]
        [-truncate [-w] <length> <path> ...]
        [-usage [cmd ...]]

Generic options supported are
-conf <configuration file>     specify an application configuration file
-D <property=value>            use value for given property
-fs <file:///|hdfs://namenode:port> specify default filesystem URL to use, overrides 'fs.defaultFS' 
 property from configurations.
-jt <local|resourcemanager:port>    specify a ResourceManager
-files <comma separated list of files>    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map 
 reduce cluster
-libjars <comma separated list of jars>    specify comma separated jar files to include in the 
 classpath.
-archives <comma separated list of archives>    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on 
the compute machines.

The general command line syntax is
command [genericOptions] [commandOptions]

Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...
OK




4 rows selected (3.61 seconds)
hive>
```

Weird thing is that it's taking 4 rows space and showing it blank.

Can't understand what's happening?

Table creation:

```sql
    create table employee (Id int, Name string , Salary float)  
    row format delimited  
    fields terminated by ',' ;
```

Loading the data in table:

```sql
load data local inpath 'C:\employee.txt' into table employee;
```

`employee.txt` file

```sql
    1 "Anurag" 40000.0
    2 "Ayush" 42000.0
    3 "Akhil" 44000.0
    4 "Aarav" 46000.0
```

Comment: Please, could you post the way you have created, loaded the table and some data example?

Comment: @Chema please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have created a table with `','` `delimited fields`, it means that the source have to have rows with fields separated by ','

Your source file

```
1 "Anurag" 40000.0
2 "Ayush" 42000.0
3 "Akhil" 44000.0
4 "Aarav" 46000.0
```

is one space delimited fields and should be

```
1,"Anurag",40000.0
2,"Ayush",42000.0
3,"Akhil",44000.0
4,"Aarav",46000.0
```

or you create table should be

```sql
create table employee (Id int, Name string , Salary float)  
row format delimited  
fields terminated by ' ' ;
```